# If eight out of nine vertexes can't be roots, is the last vertex a root?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to modelize an electrical circuit. In order to be isolated from electrical issues power has to be put in a root vertex.

Consider that $x$ is a root $iif \ \ \forall y_i \ne x,\ x$ is ascendent of  $y_i$. That is to say if there is no edges that comes **into** $x$.

If eight out of nine vertexes can't be roots, why is the last vertex a root?

Consider that $x$ is an anti-root $iif \ \ \forall y_i \ne x,\ x$ is descendent (going-out) from $y_i$. That is to say if there is no edges that comes **from** $x$.

Let consider this graph $G=(X,U)$ I have showed that eight out of nine vertexes can't be roots as far as if it were the case, one must be an anti-root of all others. Yet $g$ is outgoing of $f$ and $d$ is outgoing of $e$. Thus eight out of nine vertexes can't be root of all others.

However it doesn't show that the last vertex is actually a root!

Thus how can I show that the last vertex must be a root of $G$?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have not made it exactly clear why a node can or can't be a root (or what an *anti-root* is). I assume that the current in your graph only flows in the direction of the edges. So you could prove a node is the root by showing that there is a directed path from that node to every other node.

It looks like that if there is a root, it must be $a$ since $a$ has no edges pointing into it.

Comment: I've just given the anti-root definition, do you think it is sufficient to show that proving on the right hand that 8 vertexes can't be root and that a must be a root on the other hand?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Marine1, almagest means that your question is poorly defined and poorly written. How do you define a *root*? How you define *descendent (going-out)*? Why is the fact that $8$ vertices are not roots relevant to finding if the last vertex is a root? ... After looking over your question, it appears that you are working with a definition of what *is not* a root, but for some reason don't want acknowledge the definition of what *is* a root. If you need to show $a$ is a root, then just see if it follows the definition.